# "concatenation function" that divides long data into up to 16 QR codes and combines them when reading in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, qr-code, barcode, zxing

Previously I asked a question about concatenation/Linked QR code Many could not understand may be because I could not explain well . My question Link is here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68341593/creating-a-linked-qr-code-or-concatenated-qr-code-with-zxing-in-c-sharp) . I want to explain and want to know how I can Implement concatenation/Linked QR code . In the Ruby site you can find here explaining concatenated QR code [enter link description here](https://linuxtut.com/ruby-generate-concatenated-qr-code-with-rqrcode-(knowledge)-3dd4c/) . As it is mainly used in Japan . In My previous question I explain what I did again I want to mention that .   I can create a QR code using Zxing in C#. Here is my code.Here I write QR Code with some value come from TextBox. How I create the QR Code and retrieve? Please Note that I read and write QR code in C# and Zxing Library

```
        var qrcodeWritter = new BarcodeWriter();

        qrcodeWritter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;

        QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions()
        {

            DisableECI = true, // ​​set the content encoding
            CharacterSet = "UTF-8", //Set the width and height of the QR code
            Width = 600,
            Height = 600,
            Margin = 1//Set the margin of the QR code, the unit is not a fixed pixel

        };

        tt = txtFileName.Text;

        qrcodeWritter.Options = options;
        qrcodeWritter.Write("Name" + $" {txtName.Text} /n" + "Email" + $"{txtEmail.Text} /n" + "Name as the file to save" + $"{txtFileName.Text}")
            .Save(@"C:\Demo_Project_Barcode\QRImage\" + $"{txtFileName.Text}.bmp");


Here You can See I did QR Code writting from TextBox that is Input Section. Here is the
```

Section I read from files .

```
var fileContent = string.Empty;
        var filePath = string.Empty;

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();


        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "BarCode Files (*.bmp;*.BMP)|*.bmp;*.bmp|All files (*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }
        var qrcodebitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(filePath);
        var qrcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
        var qrcodeResult = qrcodeReader.Decode(qrcodebitmap);

        MessageBox.Show(qrcodeResult.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(qrcodeResult.BarcodeFormat.ToString());
```

Please I want to give you a picture so that you may be understand . Here you see information may be divided into 4 parts and then it become into one parts . How can I do that .I also find a Link that is written in Japanease so that I could not understand well I want to show you here .[enter link description here](https://programresource.net/2013/05/04/2188.html) [image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at this: https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/master/Clients/WPFDemo/WPFDemo/MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: No ,Okay  I am trying this . Is this for concatenated QR code

Comment: No, but I figured your first problem was to generate the barcode?

Comment: I'm not familier with zxing library, but I would guess that the generated barcode is a `byte[]`. From here it seems you need to split up the bytes in 4 bits by shifting and stuff according to the description. But that is as far as I can help.

Comment: I can Generate Barcode or QR Code . But I want to do like the image I shared it is concatenated QR code . In Japanease It is said 連結QRコード. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Michael Thanks I will try on your way . But I have not got fully your point I have to try .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234806/discussion-between-rifat-murtuza-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

zxing and ZXing.Net don't support the generation of qr codes with structured append. They can decode it but they can't encode it. You have to use another library or go the hard way and implement it yourself. You will find some information about the structured append feature at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code